# Curl c example for webdav put with digest authentication on Apache server

Tags: c, apache, curl, webdav

I am trying to write curl c code to using the http webdav put method to upload a file.

Using wireshark I have tried to capture the packets, there is 301 response from the server.

When I try to put the file from the PC to webserver it works fine

Below is the code:

```
    static size_t read_callback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
  size_t retcode;
  curl_off_t nread;

  /* in real-world cases, this would probably get this data differently
     as this fread() stuff is exactly what the library already would do
     by default internally */ 
  retcode = fread(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);

  nread = (curl_off_t)retcode;

  fprintf(stderr, "*** We read %" CURL_FORMAT_CURL_OFF_T
          " bytes from file\n", nread);

  return retcode;
}

int curlApache ()
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  FILE * hd_src;
  struct stat file_info;

  char *file;
  char *url;

  char error;

  file = "/bd0/filecreate.txt";

  url = "http://10.1.21.14/webdav/test.txt";

  curl_slist *slist = NULL; 
  slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Accept: text/xml"); 
  slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Depth: infinity"); 
  slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Connection: Keep-Alive"); 
  slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Content-Type: text/xml"); 
  slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Expect:"); 

  /* get the file size of the local file */ 
  stat(file, &file_info);


  hd_src = fopen(file, "a+");
  if (hd_src == NULL)             
  printf("Disc full or no permission\n");



  const char *str = "This is the file content";
  const char read[24];
      if (hd_src != NULL) 
      if (fputs (str, hd_src) != EOF); 
      if( fgets (read, 24, hd_src)!=NULL ) 
      {
            /* writing content to stdout */
            puts(read);
      }

  /* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */ 
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

  /* get a curl handle */ 
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 3L);

    /* we want to use our own read function */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, read_callback);

    /* enable uploading */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);

    /* HTTP PUT please */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1L);

    /* tell libcurl we can use "any" auth, which lets the lib pick one, but it also costs one extra round-trip and possibly sending of all the PUT                data twice!!! */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, (long)CURLAUTH_DIGEST); 


   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "admin:nimo0630");

    fseek(hd_src, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int file_size;
    file_size = ftell(hd_src);

    Curl_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILE, hd_src);
    Curl_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, file_size);

    /* specify target URL, and note that this URL should include a file
       name, not only a directory */  

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);

    /* now specify which file to upload */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, hd_src);

    /* provide the size of the upload, we specicially typecast the value
       to curl_off_t since we must be sure to use the correct data size */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE, curl_off_t)file_info.st_size);

    /* Now run off and do what you've been told! */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));


        if(!res) {
          /* extract the available authentication types */
        long auth;
        res = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_HTTPAUTH_AVAIL, &auth);
        if(!res) 
        {
            if(!auth)
            printf("No auth available, perhaps no 401?\n");
            else
            {     
                printf("%s%s%s%s\n", \
                    auth & CURLAUTH_BASIC ? "Basic ":"", \
                    auth & CURLAUTH_DIGEST ? "Digest ":"", \
                    auth & CURLAUTH_NEGOTIATE ? "Negotiate ":"", \
                    auth % CURLAUTH_NTLM ? "NTLM ":"");
            }

        }
        }
    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  fclose(hd_src); /* close the local file */ 

  curl_global_cleanup();
  return 0;
}
```

There is status code 301 returned from the server

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to understand how to debug this issue. If you paste your code, a more specific answer can be provided.

1. First check if you are able to upload file using command line curl. This will tell you if server is working fine
2. Check if the options you use are provided in C API
3. Check the API's are not returning any error
4. You could use tcpdump / wireshark to capture packets on the client or server to see if packets went out and what was the http content. You may not see any packet if API failed

Comment: Hi Vishal thanks for the suggestions. I have updated my http webdav  code using the curl library.